# How to format time using momentjs when you get the data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs, ejs, node-modules

I don't know how to format time using moments when I get the data from MongoDB

I have tried `<%= m(blog.created).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')%>`

```
var moment = require('moment');
 var m = moment();
```

this is in my app.js setting up the Schema

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:  String,
    author: String,
    body:   String,
    image: String,
    created: {type:Date, default:Date.now}
});
```

on my Show.ejs page

```
<div class="ui text main container segment">
 <div class="ui huge header"><%=blog.title%></div>
    <div class="ui top attached">
        <div class="item">
            <img class="ui centered rounded image" src="<%=blog.image%>">
            <div class="content">

                <span><%=blog.created%></span>

            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <p><%=blog.body%></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want the date format to be like this

moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // February 6th 2019, 2:31:46 am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var moment = require('moment');
app.locals.moment = require('moment'); // this makes moment available as a variable in every EJS page
```

and on Show.ejs

```
<%= moment(blog.created).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')%>
```